# Woocommerce save order items - problem with cycle

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I made select box to items on admin order detail page to change tax class. Can someone see the problem why it cannot be saved?
 It writes: 
**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_tax_class() on null. 
Thanks guys

```
function tax_change($item_id, $item, $product) {
    if('line_item' === $item->get_type()){
    ?>
        <td class="line_changetax" style="width:20%">
            <select name="change_tax" id="change_tax_select" style="width:90%; display:inline-block">
                <?php
                $arraytax = WC_Tax::get_tax_class_slugs();
                    echo '<option value="'.$item->get_tax_class().'">'.$item->get_tax_class().'</option>';
                foreach($arraytax as $tax){
                    echo '<option value="'.$tax.'">'.$tax.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'tax_change', 10, 3 );

function change_order_item_tax_class( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item_id) {
        $item = $items[$item_id];
        $item->set_tax_class($_POST['change_tax']);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 'change_order_item_tax_class', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: As I have told you before in your other answer, you will not get any value on `$_POST['change_tax']`, as your "change_tax" select field value isn't posted on submission…  It requires something much more complex driven by Ajax, a real development like. Now your code has a lot of mistakes, as for example `$item` is not defined.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec So how is it possible it works like that [video](https://streamable.com/z028xs) with this code 
`
function change_order_item_tax_class( $item ) {
    if (isset($_POST['change_tax']) ) {
        $item->set_tax_class($_POST['change_tax']);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_save_order_item', 'change_order_item_tax_class' ); 
`